# How can I avoid variable re-declaration for #define syntax?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

When we pass parameter of class type in c++, we have no choice but to use #define.
But this makes the code messy.

```
#include <vector>
#define APPEND(className) \
        base = new className(); \
        baseVector.push_back(base); \

class Base{};
class Child1 : public Base{};
class Child2 : public Base{};
// ...
class Child10 : public Base{};
std::vector<Base*> baseVector;
int main(void){
    Base* base; // I want to remove this
    APPEND(Child1);
    APPEND(Child2);
    // ...
    APPEND(Child10);
}
```

If I put **Base* base** in #define syntax,  redeclaration error occurs.
However, it looks awkward if I just let it be.

```
#define APPEND(className) \
        #ifndef DECL \
        Base* base; \
        #define DECL \
        #endif \
        base = new className(); \
        baseVector.push_back(base); \
```

This is not possible. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just `baseVector.push_back(new className());`?

Comment: @immibis This is just a short example. Actually, the code block inside the #define is very long. Anyway this question is of no use anymore. I should have used a template like vmario mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `#define` to wrap its code in its own set of brackets, then it can declare its own local variable every time it calls `push_back()`.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <vector>

#define APPEND(className) \
{ \
    Base *base = new className(); \
    try { \
        baseVector.push_back(base); \
    } catch (...) { \
        delete base; \
        throw; \
    } \
}

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Child1 : public Base {};
class Child2 : public Base {};
// ...
class Child10 : public Base {};

std::vector<Base*> baseVector;

int main(void){
    APPEND(Child1);
    APPEND(Child2);
    APPEND(Child3);
    // ...
    APPEND(Child10);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all your code doesn't even compile. Here is a fixed version:

```
#include <vector>

class Base{};

class Child1 : public Base {};
class Child2 : public Base {};

std::vector<Base*> baseVector;

int main(void)
{
    baseVector.push_back( new Child1 );
    baseVector.push_back( new Child2 );

    return 0;
}
```

You absolutely don't need any `#define` tricks.
This is almost always bad practice, and certainly in your case.

Comment: The other answer has a try around the push_back call.  Can it throw bad_alloc on reallocation failure?  If it does then the new ChildX will leak.  I guess that's ok if you aren't planning to catch the bad_alloc exception anyway but it probably isn't optimal in an embedded controller that needs to recover from any failure and keep running.

Comment: How about using unique_ptr instead of raw pointers. Is out-of-memory even a real issue? Most programs I know simply don't have a good way of dealing with that even when they want to

Answer (score 2):

> When we pass parameter of class type in c++, we have no choice but to use #define.

We have choice. We can use templates:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void hello() = 0;
};

class Child1: public Base {
    void hello() { cout << "Child1" << endl; }
};

class Child2: public Base {
    void hello() { cout << "Child2" << endl; }
};

class Child3: public Base {
    void hello() { cout << "Child3" << endl; }
};

vector<Base*> baseVector;

template<typename T>
void append() {
    Base* child = new T{};

    try {
        baseVector.push_back(child);
    } catch (...) {
        delete child;
        throw;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    append<Child1>();
    append<Child2>();
    append<Child3>();

    for (auto child : baseVector) {
        child->hello();
    }

    for (auto child : baseVector) {
        delete child;
    }
}
```

But you should avoid `new` and `delete` operators and simply use smart pointers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void hello() = 0;
};

class Child1: public Base {
    void hello() { cout << "Child1" << endl; }
};

class Child2: public Base {
    void hello() { cout << "Child2" << endl; }
};

class Child3: public Base {
    void hello() { cout << "Child3" << endl; }
};

vector<unique_ptr<Base>> baseVector;

int main(void){
    baseVector.push_back(make_unique<Child1>());
    baseVector.push_back(make_unique<Child2>());
    baseVector.push_back(make_unique<Child3>());

    for (auto& child : baseVector) {
        child->hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I have no idea why I couldn't think about using a template. Thanks!